Missing Installation parameters when trying to install SQL Server 2022 from the command prompt
I need to install SQL Server 2022 express on a Windows machine from the command line. Following this guide, I downloaded the executable and run:
.\SQL2022-SSEI-Expr.exe /Q /Action="install" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="password"

It returns the following error message:

The setting 'securitymode' specified is not recognized.
The setting 'sapwd' specified is not recognized.

Using the help it only shows the following parameters:

Action
Configurationfile
Enu
Help
Hideprogressbar
Iacceptsqlserverlicenseterms
Installpath
Language
Mediapath
Mediatype
Quiet
Verbose

Using this parameters the installation works as expected, but I need to change the security mode during installation.

SQL2022-SSEI-Expr.exe sounds like you're running the wrong file. The file should be setup.exe i think

Run SQL2022-SSEI-Expr.exe, and choose Download Media.  Choose "Express Core", and you'll download SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe.  Run that to extract the full install media to a folder, which you can use for the unattended installation.

This was the answer, thanks!
